# If we use an array of linked list to implement hash table, "add" could be implemented in a way that no traversing is needed. Is this true or false?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

If we use an array of linked list to implement hash table, "add" could be implemented in a way that no traversing is needed. Is this true or false? I'm confused which one it is because I read the book and I just can't quiet understand the question. If you can also post a brief description why the answer is either T or F so I can get a grasp understanding that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is true.

The question basically translates to this:

> When a collision occurs, is it necessary to add new values to the end of the linked list, and thus traverse the whole list in the process?

The proposed implementation is an array of linked lists. The linked lists are merely there to handle collisions, which means the nodes they contain don't need to be in any particular order.

When a collision happens, you simply create a new node and set it as the head of the linked list. Prepending a node to a linked list is trivial and does not require traversing the complete list.

**As a side note:** lookup will require you to traverse the linked list.

## A Visual Example

Assume a hash table of size 3 that stores animals. It currently contains 'bear', 'lion' and 'eagle':

```
+---+
| 0 | -> 0
+---+
| 1 | -> bear -> lion -> 0
+---+
| 2 | -> eagle -> 0
+---+
```

Image we try to add 'fox', the hash function returns 1. The table at index 1 already has a list of two animals: a collision!

Instead of appending 'fox' to the end of that list, and thus traversing the whole list, we'll simply make 'fox' the new head of the list:

```
+---+
| 0 | -> 0
+---+
| 1 | -> fox -> bear -> lion -> 0
+---+
| 2 | -> eagle -> 0
+---+
```

## A Code Example

```cpp
template <class KeyType, class ValueType, int Size>
class HashTable {

    template <class ValueType>
    struct LinkedList {
        ValueType value;
        LinkedList* next;
    }

    int hash(const Key& key) {
        // some hash algorithm
    }

    LinkedList* table[Size]; // the array that stores pointers to LinkedLists

public:
    void add(KeyType key, ValueType value) {
        int index = hash(key);
        LinkedList new_entry = new LinkedList();
        new_entry.value = value;
        // The next line of code has two possible outcomes:
        // 1. table[index] contains a nullpointer, it is thus empty and new_entry.next will be set to null.
        // 2. table[index] contains a pointer to a LinkedList, new_entry.next will then also point to that LinkedList.
        new_entry.next = table[index];
        table[index] = new_entry;
    }
};
```